# Create a form responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, flexbox

I created a form

Wondering how can I use flexbox to make it responsive.

I am new to flexbox so i am still working on it.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="form">

    <form action="#">
            <div>
                    <p class="title">BORGE</p>

                    <p>
                            <label for="email">E-mail : </label>
                            <input type="email" id="email">
                    </p>

                    <p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn">
                    </p>
            </div>

    </form>


</div>
```

Any idea how can I incorporate flexbox on it?

If you could show me the JSFIDDLE as well.

Comment: Where is the CSS you've tried? Maybe post an image of the layout you want?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of noise in that code. Next time you submit a question try to clear things up a bit.

You didn't specify that you expect 2 forms to be next to eachother so I only used one like in your example.

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.form{
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title{
  font-size: 25px;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 40px;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4d4d4d;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
  cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: auto;
}

input:not([type="submit"]){
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  display: flex;
}

label {
    width: 7em;
    margin-right: .5em;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  p {
    display: block;
  }
  input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form">

<form action="#">
  <div>
    <p class="title">BORGE</p>
    <p>
      <label for="first name">User Name : </label>
      <input type="text" id="first_name" autofocus>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="last name"> Last name : </label>
      <input type="text" id="last_name">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">E-mail : </label>
      <input type="email" id="email">
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn">
    </p>
  </div>

</form>
  
</div>
```